# Poisson Approximation of Binomial

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have to prove the Poisson approximation of the Binomial distribution using generating functions and have outlined my proof here.

Given,

\begin{align}
& \lim_{n\to \infty} np_n = \lambda \\
& G_n(z) = (1+p_n(z-1))^n & \text{(Binomial generating function)} \\
& G(z) = e^{\lambda(z-1)} & \text{(Poisson generating function)} \\
\end{align}

My proof is as follows,

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} G_n(z) & = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1+ p_n(z-1))^n \\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \frac {np_n(z-1)}{n}\right)^n \\ 
& = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \frac {\lambda(z-1)}{n}\right)^n \tag a \\
& = e^{\lambda(z-1)} \\
& = G(z)
\end{align}

I am not confident about step (a).
I don't think I can apply the limit to just a limited part of the fraction to get $\lambda$ and then apply the rule to get $e$.

Can someone please explain if (a) is valid and if not explain how to proceed from this point.

Comment: Use the fact $\lambda_n \rightarrow \lambda$ then $(1+\frac{\lambda_n}{n})^n \rightarrow e^{\lambda}$. So do not write step (a), instead denote $\lambda_n=np_n(z-1)$

Comment: Can you tell me why $(1 + \frac {\lambda_n} n)^n \to e^\lambda$ is valid. Isn't that limit defined for $(1 + \frac t n)^n$ only where $t$ is a constant? That's essentially my question.

Comment: @SrinivasEswar Isn´t $\lambda (z-1)$ a constant ?

Comment: @calculus Yes it is but $\lambda_n$ isn't. So can we take a $\lim_{n \to \infty} np_n(z-1)$ separately inside the the brackets and then take an overall limit?

Comment: @SrinivasEswar I don´t think that this is operation is valid. But you can start to calculate with limits some steps later.

Comment: @SrinivasEswar Forget the second part of my last comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complete the proof you need to show that $\lambda_n\rightarrow \lambda$ implies $(1+\lambda_n/n)^n\rightarrow e^{\lambda}$. Here's the proof:

$$(1+\lambda_n/n)^n=\exp(n\log(1+\lambda_n/n)).$$

Now expand the log:

$$n\log(1+\lambda_n/n)=n\left(\frac{\lambda_n}{n}+O(\lambda^2_n/n^2)\right)=\lambda_n+nO(\lambda^2_n/n^2).$$

Notice that $n\cdot O(\lambda^2_n/n^2)\rightarrow 0$. Now pass the limit through the exponential and you're done.

Comment: I have a question regarding another way to prove this, would you mind [taking a look](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262330/show-lim-left-left-1-1-s-frac-lambda-nn-rightn-left1-1-s-frac)? :)